# Numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (5,2)

Tags: numpy

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (5,2)
```

And i'm not sure where it went wrong. Btw the question requires us to find `w` as the final ans. Any recommendations on what should be done?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
def A1_number(X, y):
    XT = np.transpose(X)
    #print(XT)
    InvXTX = np.linalg.inv(XT*X)
    #print(InvXTX)
    Xt = (InvXTX)*XT
    #print(Xt)
    InvXtX = np.linalg.inv(Xt*X)
    w = InvXtX*(Xt*y)
    #return w


    # return in this order
    return InvXTX, w
print(A1_number([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]], [0,0,1,0,0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the values you are passing are off; hence the **value error**.

- ### 5 x 2

A = `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10], [missing second array]]`

- ### 2 x 5

B =  `[[0,0,1,0,0], [missing array]]`

Hope it was helpful.